Get all items modified in a given day with manual trigger
I am trying to get all items modified within a given day in flow. Problem is, it only returns the latest version of a single column. I would like to get the new value of all modified item in the list. For context, the two columns have version history turned on so it's not giving me an option for Value. I am also using a timed trigger (recurrence).



Why can’t you use the “when an item is modified” then? It’ll always give you the current values.

I can't use that because it's an email that sends monthly. I'm creating a html table.

But you want to capture all versions of a field. Have two flows then and make one the event based trigger when an item is modified, capture the data then run your monthly flow and process all of the data.

Thanks. Ended up doing a variation of this (loading changes in excel and filtering from there).
